# How to update SAGA tools on a Mac OSX

Tags: saga, mac

I am running QGIS 3.20 on my MacOS Monterey and it is working fine. Now I need to update the SAGA tools as it is well below (it has SAGA 7.3.0 and I am getting the message that it is not supported - it looks that SAGA is now on 8.0)

How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps review these Q&As: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saga+mac

Answer (score 0):

you need to deactivate SAGA in processing toolbox and install SAGANG (SAGA next gen)
But you anyway may struggle with things like up-slope area etc.